# HashMap$Values cannot be cast to class HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have this class Turnier where I implement a HashMap.
But once I use a reference of it, I get a error.

```
package data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Turnier implements Comparable<Turnier> {
    
    private String name;
    private int year;
    
    private Collection<Match> matches = new ArrayList <Match>() ;
    private Map<String, Spieler> spieler = new HashMap<String,Spieler>(); 
    
    public Turnier(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        
        this.year = Integer.parseInt(this.name.substring(this.name.length() - 4));
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    
    public Collection<Match> getMatches() {
        return this.matches;
    }
    
    public void addMatch(Match match) {
        
        getMatches().add(match);
    }
        
    public void addSpieler(Spieler spieler) {
        
        getSpieler().put(spieler.getID(), spieler);
    }
    
    public Map<String, Spieler> getSpieler() {
        return this.spieler;
    }
    
    public int getJahr() {
        return this.year;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Turnier t2) {
        return this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(t2.name);
    }
    
}
```

But when I try to use the HashMap via getters,like this: I always get a exception

> HashMap$Values cannot be cast to class HashMap

```
package io;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import data.Ergebnis;
import data.Satz;
import data.Match;
import data.Spieler;
import data.Turnier;

public class CSVReader extends Reader {

    public CSVReader(String filename) {
        super(filename);
    }

    public CSVReader(File file) {
        super(file);
    }

    
    public void parseLine(String line) {
        String[] tokens = getTokens(line);
        System.out.print(tokens[3]);
        
        if(((HashMap<String,Spieler>)getSpieler()).containsKey("a")) {
            
        }
        
        
        
    }

    
    public String[] getTokens(String line) {
        String[] tokens = line.split(";");
        return tokens;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void parseFile() {
        try (BufferedReader bufR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.file))) {
            String line;
            bufR.readLine(); // erste Zeile ignorieren
            while ((line = bufR.readLine()) != null) {
                parseLine(line);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(general.Parameters.csvPath);
        reader.parseFile();
        reader.info();

    }
}
```

This is my Spieler Class

```
package data;

public class Spieler {
    
    private String S_ID;
    private String vorname;
    private String nachname;
    private String geburtstag;
    private String geburtsort;
    private String nationalitaet;
    
    public Spieler(String id, String vorname, String nachname, String geburtstag, String geburtsort, String nationalitaet) {
        this.S_ID = id;
        this.vorname = vorname;
        this.nachname = nachname;
        this.geburtstag = geburtstag;
        this.geburtsort = geburtsort;
        this.nationalitaet = nationalitaet;
    }
    
    public String getID() {
        return this.S_ID;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return this.vorname + " " + this.nachname;
    }
    
    public String getVorname() {
        return this.vorname;
    }
    
    public String getNachname() {
        return this.nachname;
    }
    
    public String getGeburtstag() {
        return this.geburtstag; 
    }
    
    public String getGeburtsort() {
        return this.geburtsort; 
    }
    
    public String getNationalitaet() {
        return this.nationalitaet;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return this.getName();
    }
}
```

This is my Reader Class

```
 package io;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import data.Spieler;
import data.Turnier;

public abstract class Reader {
    protected File file;
    protected Map <String, Spieler> spieler;
    protected Map <String, Turnier> turniere;

    public Reader(String filename) {
        this(new File(filename));
    }
    
    public abstract void parseFile();
    
    public Reader (File file) {
        this.file = file;
        this.spieler = new HashMap<>();
        this.turniere = new HashMap<>();
    }
    
    public Collection<Spieler> getSpieler() {
        return this.spieler.values();
    }
    

    public Collection<Turnier> getTurniere() {
        return this.turniere.values();
    }
    
    public void info() {
        System.out.println(this.spieler.values().size() + " Spieler");
        //System.out.println(this.spiele.values().size() + " Spiele");
        System.out.println(this.turniere.values().size() + " Turniere");
    }
}
```

Also, when I don't do the type cast

> (HashMap<String,Spieler>)this.getSpieler()).containsKey("a")
> I get the error
> The method containsKey(String) is undefind for type Collection
> which is weird to me since the return value of my get method is supposed to be HashMap<String,Spieler>
> and not Collection

Comment: I suspect your `getSpieler()` is actually returning `this.spieler.values()` in the real code, or something similar is going on. When I run a modified version of this code, with modifications just to make it compile (e.g. replace the undeclared `Spieler` class with `Integer`), it compiles fine: https://ideone.com/qSrmX6

Comment: This is obviously not your real code. Can you post the actual code?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I edited it to be the exact same code that use. I do not use the values() command in my getSpieler() method

Comment: `if((this.getSpieler()).containsKey("a")) {` <-- this is in a class that doesn't have a `getSpieler()` (unless `Reader` is a class you define, in which case you haven't showed it to us), and the parentheses don't even match.

Comment: @yshvit oh yes you are right i have a reader class with the getSpieler() method. How can I make sure that i use the getSpieler() Method from my Turnier Class ?

Comment: You already have `getSpieler() within `Turnier` (though it sounds like maybe a different implementation). The best way to call the one from `Reader` within `Turnier` is to just have a reference to the `Reader` within `Turnier` — though that sounds like it may set up a cyclic dependency (which works, but has maintenance problems as your code gets bigger). What does `Reader.getSpieler()` look like?

Comment: @yshavit I edited it  to show the Reader class. I am trying to use the getSpieler() implementation from Turnier within my CSVReader class.

Comment: @NaCl Here's the thing: This code __is not__ what you are actually running. You said it was; it clearly is not, because if it had been, `getSpieler()` would have been a compilation error (or, `CSVReader` is your class, and it's not in your paste). Edit the question again and this time copy and paste _exactly_.

Comment: `Collection<Spieler> getSpieler() { return this.spieler.values(); }` <-- there's your problem. A Collection is not a Map, and it doesn't have a `containsKey()` method.

Comment: @rzwitserloot CSVReader is my class and it is in my post. This is exactly what I run. The package does contain more classes but I do not think they are relevent for the problem. Basically my problem is that i have the getSpieler() MEthod two times. Once in my Turnier class and once in my Reader class. Right now with my current code I am uesing the getSpieler Method in my Reader class, wich does not work. I think i only have to figure out how to use the getSpieler() from my Turnier class

Comment: See @yshavit's comment.

Answer (score 1):

The call

```
if(((HashMap<String,Spieler>)getSpieler()).containsKey("a"))
```

is in CSVReader.  CSVReader extends Reader, which contains

```
public Collection<Spieler> getSpieler() {
    return this.spieler.values();
}
```

If 'spieler' is a Map, which it is, then [per the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) the return of values() is a Collection of the values in the Map.  Not the Map.

Therefore the call in CSVReader is a call to that routine in Reader, and it returns a Collection of Spielers, which (as the error message said) is not castable to any kind of Map.